# CMD Batch: Find default gateway IP address, remove spaces (if any), and open default gateway in browser

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ip-address

So I'm trying to figure out how to get the default gateway address and open it into a web browser, for the purposes of helping other people set up port forwarding in order to host some type of program (ventrilo, teamspeak, drawpile, or whatever). The problem I have is that it generates a space in the stored IP address in the beginning, which I don't want. I've been trying to change it but I can't figure out how to do it. Most of the time for me, scripting seems to be stumbling around in the dark trying to figure things out. I'm self taught!

That being said, if there are any good resources you know of to learn this sort of stuff, I'd appreciate it as well. Thanks!

```
set "ip="
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|findstr "Default"') do if not defined ip set ip=%%b
echo.
echo  The Gateway is: "%ip%"
echo.
echo Listing all available adapters IP and MAC addresses.
echo -------------------------------------------------------
ipconfig /all | findstr /R /C:"IP.* Address" /C:"Physical Address"
echo.
echo.

echo Opening web pages on...
explorer http://%IP%
pause
```

Comment: Use the space as one of your delimiters in your FOR command.

Comment: @Squashman - that would make the receiving variable `%l` for my machine. Might work on machines in one language and OS version. Might not on others.

Comment: @Squashman I tried using a space and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @lit Good to know that it could have worked that way if I changed the variable but not others. I appreciate the info.

Comment: If you wanted to use the @Squashman, you also need to change `tokens=1-12` and `%%l`. Alternatively, set `tokens=12` and use `%%a`.

Comment: Sorry. I should have explained the tokens change.

Answer (score 0):

To remove first space from IP variable use this:

```
SET IP=%IP:~1%
```

More substring examples can be found [HERE](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info as well as the resource on it. I had looked at it before but I guess I wasn't really absorbing the information, so I got something to eat first before coming back to the problem. Looks like the ~1% is just telling it to skip the first character and move on to the rest to store into the variable. Which is just perfect, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space by taking a substring of the variable from character one (1).

```
SET "ip=%ip:~1"
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the info. Just curious why you used the quotes on that.

Comment: The quotes on a SET statement ensure that there are no invisible characters (such as SPACE or TAB) at the end of the string.